# CocoaPodsを使ってライブラリーではなくExample（サンプルアプリ）をinstallsして動かしたい。

Tags: ios, swift

#### 実現したいこと

CocoaPodsを使ってライブラリーではなくExample（サンプルアプリ）をinstallsして動かしたい。
以下のライブラリーを使おうとインストールしました。Example（サンプルアプリ）があるので参考にしようとしているのですがインスールの方法がわかりません。
ディレクトリーを指定してインストールなどできるのでしょうか。
ご教示お願いいたします。
https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda/tree/master/Example

#### 実行したこと。

https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda
・ライブラリー自体はインストールできました。ただExampleファイルがありません。
・手動でGithubからZipファイルをDLしましたが、3つほどエラーがでています。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/21289

Answer (score 1):

以下、Exampleを動かすのが主目的という認識での回答になります。
※もしCocoaPodsでExampleをインストールしたいというのが主目的でしたら読み飛ばしてください

また

- Xcode7.1.x
- CocoaPods 0.39.0

で実施した手順です。

1. ダウンロードしたzipファイルを解凍する
   ※ 手元に解凍済みのものがあっても、一度削除して再度解凍した方が良いかもしれません
2. Podfileを編集する
   Koloda-master/Example配下のPodfileを下記のように編集する

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!

target 'Koloda_Example', :exclusive => true do
  pod "pop", "~> 1.0"
  pod "Koloda", "~> 2.0.4"
end

post_install do |installer|
    `find Pods -regex 'Pods/pop.*\\.h' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' 's/\\(\\)/\\"\\2\\"/'`
end
```

3. pod installを実行する
4. Koloda.xcworkspaceを起動する
5. ビルドする

手元ではこれで起動まで確認できました。

Comment: 上記で起動できました！助かりました。
ご回答いただきまして、ありがとうございます。